# Cannot install bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gcc, bcrypt

I'm trying to install `bcrypt` but get a `gcc` error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150725-48409-euca4n.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wshorten-64-to-32'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wdivision-by-zero'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wextra-tokens'
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@my_app/gems/bcrypt-3.1.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@my_app/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0/bcrypt-3.1.10/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I installed `gcc` with `homebrew` and tried version 4.9.3 and 5.2

My current `gcc --version`:

```
gcc (Homebrew gcc49 4.9.3) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Why can't `gcc` handle these command line options?

Comment: Do you have Xcode with command line tools installed? Also might try uninstalling rvm and reinstalling to make sure its linked to the proper version of gcc

Comment: Yes, Xcode is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

The `/usr/local/bin/gcc` led to `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3/bin/gcc-4.9` which didn't work.

So I removed the symlink and created a new one linking to `/usr/bin/gcc_mavericks` and that solved the problem :)

Comment: I just switched /usr/local/bin/gcc to point to /usr/bin/clang and that fixed it for me. I guess maybe gcc just doesn't have those compiler flags like clang does.